# Big Sur 11.2 sound autoswitch to external headphones

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, big-sur, sound-volume

After I updated my Macbook Pro 2020 13" to Big Sur I am getting very annoying autoswitch on my sound output to some "External Headphones" and then randomly get switched back to "MacBook Pro Speakers"

I don't have any external headphones connected to my Mac via audio cable or bluetooth.

Is it possible to remove this "External Headphones" somehow or to stop this annoying autoswitch?

[image]

Sometimes I don't even see this "External Headphones" in my audio devices and then it appears somehow and switch automatically.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any devices connected to your Mac that might act as speakers, like a monitor or recording equipment?

Comment: I have airpods but when they are connected they are listed as 3rd device it Output section. No other devices connected. It also disconnects airpods same as macbook speakers. :(